# Generic lazy-initialization with scala

Tags: scala, lazy-initialization, type-parameter

I didn't want to write alot of boilerplate code, so I decided to write generic method for lazy-init.

```
import java.util._
import concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap

object GenericsTest {
  val cache: ConcurrentHashMap[Long, 
    ConcurrentHashMap[Long, 
      ConcurrentHashMap[Long, 
        ConcurrentHashMap[Long, Long]]]] = new ConcurrentHashMap()

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val x = get(cache, 1)(() => new ConcurrentHashMap())
    val y = get(x, 1)(() => new ConcurrentHashMap())
    val z = get(y, 1)(() => new ConcurrentHashMap())
  }

  def get[B, A](map: ConcurrentHashMap[A, B], a: A)(factory: () => B): B = {
    if (map.containsKey(a)) {
      map.get(a)
    } else {
      val b = factory()
      map.put(a, factory())
      b
    }
  }
}
```

This example is only running with hard-coded **Long** but not with generic **A**, what can be the problem? Maybe there is another way to do such things?

Comment: Can you show exactly what it is that doesn't work, and explain in what way it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
val x = get(cache, 1)(() => new ConcurrentHashMap())
```

The problem is that the type of 1 is *Int*.

We have this method signature:

```
get[A, B](map: ConcurrentHashMap[A, B], a: A)(factory: () => B): B
```

The types of parameters passed in that problematic call are (B is that long nested type, it's irrelevant now):

```
ConcurrentHashMap[Long, B] and Int
```

So the compiler calculates that *A* must be the closest common ancestor of *Long* and *Int*, which is *AnyVal*, so finally it will use the passed parameters with the types of:

```
ConcurrentHashMap[AnyVal, B] and AnyVal
```

But ConcurrentHashMap is invariant in it's first type parameter, so the *cache* val can't be used as *ConcurrentHashMap[AnyVal, B]*, so the compiler gives this error message (removed the long nested type parameter part, it doesn't matter now):

```
found   : java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[Long, ...]
required: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap[AnyVal, ...]
Note: Long <: AnyVal, but Java-defined class ConcurrentHashMap is invariant in type K.
```

To fix this you need to pass the second parameter as *Long*:

```
val x = get(cache, 1L)(() => new ConcurrentHashMap())
val y = get(x, 1L)(() => new ConcurrentHashMap())
val z = get(y, 1L)(() => new ConcurrentHashMap())
```